# nginx : gizip_static : appears to not be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gzip, unicorn

Ok my stack is Ubuntu, Nginx 1, and Unicorn. I want to have Nginx serve precompiled gzips of static content.

relevant nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_http_version   1.1;
  gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;
  expires 24h;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

then from another sf question I ran strace to see if they were being requested, the results:

```
open("/media/sf_ape/public/assets/application-ae30e133eabbb10d9464189d3fb71e25.js.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE) = 9
```

I have verified this file exists. However, when I watch the access log it delivers the regular .js file not the .gz one. I have verified that the requested header specifies gzip, and that the response header is showing now gzip. I've googled quite a bit, but I haven't found an answer to my problem so far. I could have missed it somewhere, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds strange, it should have served static files.

Comment: It does serve the files; however, it does not serve the gzip versions which are in the directory with the same timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out eventually. When you run rake assets:precompile all the static assets are compiled and moved to /public. The trick is for example that the .js and the .js.gz have the exact same timestamp. Once I did touch *.gz everything served correctly. Hope that saves someone some time.